# XCode request focus during unit test run

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode4

Does anybody know how to shift window focus back to Xcode when running iOS unit tests? (I imagine this is not as much of a problem for Mac dev.) I get so annoyed having the Simulator window cover my entire Xcode project! It shouldn't even come up in the first place but that's another story. It's not much of a problem at work where I have a 27" monitor.